# how to get 3 balls with physics to animated plane working

Tags: bezier-curves

I have 3 balls "on" a plane, all with rigid bodies and active.

I have an animated plane with hook and tried both, passive and active, the balls are not reacting correctly to my animated plane.

are there restrictions i don't know or just another very dumb mistake of me?

[image]

Here is my blend file:
[image]